# how to create data structure of dynamic string?

Tags: python

I'm totally new in python, not able to find any way where I could create data structure to hold below string.

for example, below is a sample string, I can have these kind of multiple strings (as record) in a file. main variables will be static in count but elements for example in `types` can vary.

```
{"name": "pim pom",
 "types": "amy \n klim\nshining rock(ABC)\nflying\nchanning",
 "url": "http://doingrock.com",
 "image": "http://static.doingrock.com/rockisland.jpg",
 "pullTime": "PT3AM",
 "rockHeight": "8",
 "dateLive": "2010-10-14",
 "hitTime": "PT8PM",
 "desc": "Amazing view"}
```

what's a better way of create data structure in python to access elements in this string ?

please suggest

Comment: (1) What does that mean, exactly: _"...  I could create data structure to hold below string. ..."_? (2) The sample string you show is actually a dictionary? (3) Do you have JSON files/strings? If so, use the [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json) module from the standard lib.

Answer (score 0):

The way you stored the strings using python dictionary is absolutely fine. You can use list instead of string for "types", inside the dict:

```
"types": ["amy", "klim", "shining rock(ABC)", "flying", "channing"]
```

Comment: I cannot change the string type and pattern

Comment: That is also fine, you can split the string to list like that later if you need

Comment: Both ´dict´ and ´list´ can also easily stored/saved as ´.json´ file. For small and mid-sized structured datasets this is quite convenient in my opinion.